# "have you ever gone to" to ask past experience

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, formal-language, informal-language

is it correct to ask:
Have you ever gone to Spain?
if i want to know whether or not he had visited Spain in his life (experience)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by "is it correct to ask", but a more idiomatic as well as more conventional way to ask someone if they have visited a particular place at least once in their live would be:

> Have you ever been to Spain?
>
> Have you ever been to London?

You would use *been* in this situation rather than *gone*.