# Have you ever gone bungee jumping? Or, Have you ever been bungee jumping?

Tags: american-english

Have you ever gone bungee jumping?
Or, Have you ever been bungee jumping?

Which one is correct, and why? Please explain.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Have you ever been to London? Have you ever gone to London?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/58777/have-you-ever-been-to-london-have-you-ever-gone-to-london) Also [“have you ever gone to” to ask past experience.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/155965/have-you-ever-gone-to-to-ask-past-experience)

Comment: ...with "bungee jumping", there's not really any scope for the ***been / gone*** choice to have any *semantic* implications. But arguably with *Have you ever been / gone **to Spain**?*, the ***been*** version places more emphasis on ***the actual time spent in Spain*** (compare *Have you ever been **in** Spain?*), where the ***gone*** version more overtly refers to ***the journey to get there***.

Comment: Could you please undelete your first question. I have edited my answer, I hope it is clearer and I think this question is useful to future visitors. By the way, why did you delete it? I'm curious to know, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are two slightly different ways of asking exactly the same question. Both are idiomatic English.

However, the two verbs in question, **be** and **go** can signify different things in other contexts.

To say:

**My friends have gone sailing** would mean that they have departed the scene with the intention of sailing. It does not clarify whether they have arrived at the water, are still sailing or have finished sailing.

To say:

**My friends have been sailing** signifies that they have already finished sailing.

However, as you have phrased your questions, no such distinction can be drawn between them.

Comment: The original sentence has "ever", as in “**Have** *you **ever gone** to Mexico?*” people say it, but under exam conditions the more formally "correct" version would be to replace *gone* with ***been*** because if I am talking to you, it suggests that we are not currently in Mexico, the location. It seems to me it's different with *activities* such as  skiing, sailing or bungee jumping.